# como resuelvo el error Undefined variable

Tags: php, html5, crud

ya intente de todo, ahora mismo estoy en ese momento de frustracion del porque no me deja de salir este error, soy nuevo en php, asi que les dejo el codigo para ver si pueden ayudarme en algo porfavor
-----Codigo editar_cliente.php-------

```
//archivo de conexión a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';

//ID del cliente a editar
if (isset($_GET['edit_cliente'])) {
    $edit_cliente = $_GET['edit_cliente'];

    // Obtener el registro a editar de la base de datos
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE CI_cliente = '$edit_cliente'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $nombre = $row['Nombre'];
        $apellido = $row['Apellido'];
        $Ci_cliente = $row['CI_cliente'];
        $Direccion = $row['Direccion'];
        $Telefono = $row['Telefono'];
    } else {
        echo "No se encontró el cliente con el CI proporcionado.";
        exit;
    }
}
// Actualizar registro
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['Apellido'];
    $Ci_cliente = $_POST['CI_cliente'];
    $Direccion = $_POST['Direccion'];
    $Telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
    $sql = "UPDATE cliente SET Nombre='$nombre', Apellido='$apellido', CI_cliente= '$Ci_cliente', Direccion='$Direccion', Telefono='$Telefono' WHERE CI_cliente='$edit_cliente'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      // header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Error al actualizar el registro: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

// Cerrar conexión a la base de datos
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Editar Cliente</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Editar Cliente</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" required><br>
        Apellido: <input type="text" name="Apellido" value="<?php echo $apellido; ?>" required><br>
        CI: <input type="text" name="CI_cliente" value="<?php echo $Ci_cliente; ?>" required><br>
        Dirección: <input type="text" name="Direccion" value="<?php echo $Direccion; ?>" required><br>
        Teléfono: <input type="text" name="Telefono" value="<?php echo $Telefono; ?>" required><br>
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Actualizar">
        <a href="index.php">Cancelar</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

------ coidgo index.php-------

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'conexion.php';

    // Manejo de errores en la conexión
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Error al conectar a la base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Función para mostrar un mensaje de éxito o error
    function showAlert($message, $type) {
        echo '<div style="padding: 10px; background-color: ' . $type . ';">' . $message . '</div>';
    }


    // Leer registros
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
// Eliminar registro
if (isset($_GET['delete_cliente'])) {
    $delete_cliente = $_GET['delete_cliente'];

    // Eliminar el registro de la base de datos
    $sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE CI_cliente = '$delete_cliente'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        showAlert("Registro eliminado exitosamente.", "green");
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        showAlert("Error al eliminar el registro: " . mysqli_error($conn), "red");
    }
}
    ?>
    
    <!-- Lista de registros -->
    <center><h2>Clientes</h2>
    <a href="crear_cliente.php"> Nuevo</a>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Carnet de identidad</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Nombre'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Apellido'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['CI_cliente'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Direccion'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Telefono'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href= "editar_cliente.php?edit_cliente='. $row['CI_cliente'] . '">Editar</a> | <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?delete_cliente=' . $row['CI_cliente'] . '">Eliminar</a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No hay registros</td></tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</center>
    <?php
    // Cerrar conexión a la base de datos
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

si es necesaria la base de datos con gusto respondo con el query para generar la base de datos, la primera parte del codigo es para la edicion de algun dato dentro de la base de datos la primera parte es el (delete de cualquier dato ese si funiona, por cierto si se puede separar el eliminar sin que me bote el mismo error que el de editar ???) y simplemente mostraria la tabla en este caso cliente, es un crud lo que estoy tratando de hacer, pero se me complico bastante como pueden observar

Comment: Compartenos el texto o una captura del error o warning que te aparece, con eso más facil localizar el problema , aún más... si puedes por favor coloca estas 3 lineas en la cabecera de tu archivo php: ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL); , despues lo ejecutas y nos compartes acá la salida, con eso seguro te ayudamos a resolver el problema. Saludos!

Comment: ya solucione el error al parecer era que en el post del formulario perdia los datos del edit_clientes

Comment: pero el mensaje de error completo era el siguiente Undefined variable $edit_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectodb2\editar_cliente.php on line 34

Comment: ese error pero con la variable cambiada edit_cliente

Comment: Ese error que mencionas no puede producirse con el código que publicaste en la pregunta.